# Matching pairs in a list of named data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

Suppose I have 2 `list`s of named (ex. `Study1`) `data.frame`s.

I want each element `d` from each `data.frame` in the *2nd* list (`k`) to be paired with the single corresponding `d` element in the *1st* list (`j`) for the same data.frame.

For example, in the below case, for the `data.frame` named `Study1` across the two lists, I want the pairs to be: `1 3`, `1 4`, and `1 5`. And for `Study2` across the two lists, I want the pairs to be: `3 1`, `3 2`, and `3 3`?

**Update:** can we also keep the `row.names` of the the pairs (for tracking purposes)?

```
a <- data.frame(d = 1, cont = T); rownames(a) <- "bbb"
b <- data.frame(d = 3, cont = T); rownames(b) <- "ggg"
x <- data.frame(d = 3:5, cont = c(F, F, F)); rownames(x) <- paste0("xx",1:3)
y <- data.frame(d = 1:3, cont = c(F, F, F)); rownames(y) <- paste0("yy",1:3)

j <- list(Study1 = a, Study2 = b)

k <- list(Study1 = x, Study2 = y)
```

Comment: Here is one possible solution: `purrr::map2(j,k,function(x,y) paste0(x[["d"]]," ",y[["d"]]) )`

Comment: You can use `Map` from `base R` `Map(function(x, y)  paste0(x[["d"]], y[["d"]]), j, k)`

Comment: Maybe nested `lapply` or `sapply`. There could be several others, someone will probably add one.

Comment: IN that case, use `c` instead of `paste0`

Comment: Do you need `Map(function(x, y)  expand.grid(d1 = x$d, d2 = y$d), j, k)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be get the combinations of corresponding elements on the extracted 'd' columns of both `list`s with `Map`

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
                       dat <- expand.grid(x, y)
                       split(as.matrix(dat), row(dat))
   }
do.call(Map, c(f = f1, list(lapply(j, `[[`, "d"), lapply(k, `[[`, "d"))))
```

#### Update

If we also have different row names and want them as `names` in the `list` elements

```
lapply(seq_along(j), function(i) {
      x1 <- expand.grid(d1 = j[[i]]$d, d2 = k[[i]]$d)
      row.names(x1) <- c(outer(row.names(j[[i]]), row.names(k[[i]]), FUN = paste))
      setNames(split(as.matrix(x1), row(x1)), 
      paste(names(k[i]), row.names(x1), sep="_"))
      })
```

---

Or as @NelsonGon suggested, `map2` from `tidyverse` can also be used

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(j, k, ~   crossing(d1 = .x$d, d2 = .y$d) %>%
                     group_split(grp = row_number(), keep = FALSE) %>% 
                     map(flatten_dbl))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193582/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-matching-pairs-in-a-list-of-named-data-frames-in-r).